# avcodec on C, frozen image

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I write video packets from video stream to buffer. and then i'm trying to write them to file.

```
            av_init_packet( &pkt );
            int bufer_size=250;

            while ( av_read_frame( ifcx, &pkt ) >= 0 && start_flag==0 && stop_flag==0){
                printf("reading packet - %i \n", pkg_index);
                if ( pkt.stream_index == i_index ) {
                    pkt.stream_index = ost->id;
                    pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, ist->time_base, ost->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, ist->time_base, ost->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                    pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, ist->time_base, ost->time_base);
                    pkt.pos = -1;
                    av_copy_packet(&pkt_arr[pkg_index],&pkt);
                }
                av_free_packet( &pkt );
                av_init_packet( &pkt );
                pkg_index++;

                if(pkg_index>=bufer_size){

                    int ret = avformat_write_header(ofcx, NULL);
                    av_dump_format( ofcx, 0, ofcx->filename, 1 );

                        int i;
                        int start_frame=0;
                        for(i=start_frame; i<bufer_size; i++){
                            av_interleaved_write_frame( ofcx, &pkt_arr[i] );
                        }

                          av_write_trailer( ofcx );
                          avio_close( ofcx->pb );
                          printf("END \n");
                          return 0;

                }
            }
```

now the problem: if start_frame=0 everithing is ok, i have 10 sec video file.  But if start_frame=125 (for example) in resault i have video file with 5 sec frozen picture and 5 sec video.

what is wrong?

also at the end i have errors:

```
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 1
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 2
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 3
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 4
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 5
[avi @ 0x287a9f0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 6 >= 6
```

maybe you know what is it.

Answer (score 0):

It kinda says you have to re-adjust packet pts/dts for +125 frame change. Try to restamp pts/dts before `av_interleaved_write_frame`. For `pts` this simple formula may work `pkt.pts = frame_count * pkt.duration`. `dts` is more complicated but for the test puspose try `pkt.dts = pkt.pts`. Hope that helps.